# Telerik radgrid not finding key id for deletions

Tags: c#

Ok I am using a Iqueryalbe to return a data set but I am using telerik data grid to show the results.

But When I try to access the datakeyvalue I not getting any result cause that normally be set in markup

```
    public IQueryable<player> getAllPlayersByTeamId(Guid teamId)            
    {
        var _player = SoccerEntities.players.Where(a => a.teamId == teamId).ToList();
        return _player.AsQueryable();
    }
```

My Function where I call get all players

```
          Guid teamId = new Guid(Request.QueryString["teamId"].ToString());
          if (teamId ==Guid.Empty)
          {
              grdSoccerPlayers.DataSource = _dal.getAllPlayersByTeamId(teamId);
              grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
          }
```

The action Where I am trying to trap the datakeyvalue  wich be normally set by the entity datasource ?.

```
 if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            GridDataItem item = e.Item as GridDataItem;
            Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("id").ToString());

            player _player = _dal.GetPlayerBYID(strId);

            _dal.SoccerEntities.players.DeleteObject(_player);

            _dal.SoccerEntities.SaveChanges();
            grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify DataKeyNames in the RadGrid markup:

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="teamId">
```

And then you can pull the key value for a given grid item in your code-behind:

```
Guid strId = new Guid(item.GetDataKeyValue("teamId").ToString());
```

If for some reason you do not want to set DataKeyNames in the markup, you can set the property dynamically in the code-behind:

```
grdSoccerPlayers.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "teamId" };
grdSoccerPlayers.DataSource = _dal.getAllPlayersByTeamId(teamId);
grdSoccerPlayers.DataBind();
```

If the name of your primary key column is just "id" instead of "teamId" then just replace all instances of "teamId" with "id" in my example.